# Adding filter to INNER JOIN with 3 tables

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I would like to perform a SQL in Marketing Cloud on 3 data extensions, but for each join I would like to create a filter (a WHERE). I'm worried about the positioning because the WHERE clause would always go at the end of the SQL when I was joining 2 data extensions. Below's the example:

```
SELECT  a.userGroupID, a.userID, a.fname, a.lname,
        b.order_ID,user_ID,purchase_amount,purchase_date
        c.opt-in,c.user_ID
FROM    Users a
        INNER JOIN Orders b
            ON a.userID = b.orderlD
        WHERE purchase_date = 'true'
        INNER JOIN Permissions c
            ON b.userID = c.userID
        WHERE opt-in = 'true';
```

Is this the right to do it positioning-wise and in terms of commands, or should I use 2 ANDs instead? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The where clause should be at the end of your sql statement, similar to this:

```
SELECT  a.userGroupID, a.userID, a.fname, a.lname,
        b.order_ID,user_ID,purchase_amount,purchase_date
        c.opt-in,c.user_ID
FROM    Users a
        INNER JOIN Orders b
            ON a.userID = b.orderlD
        INNER JOIN Permissions c
            ON b.userID = c.userID
        WHERE c.opt-in = 'true' and b.purchase_date = 'true'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `where` needs to go after the joins:

```
SELECT  
  a.userGroupID
, a.userID
, a.fname
, a.lname
, b.order_ID
, b.purchase_amount
, b.purchase_date
, c.[opt-in]
, c.user_ID
FROM Users a
INNER JOIN Orders b ON b.userID = a.userId
INNER JOIN Permissions c ON c.userID = a.userID
WHERE b.purchase_date is not null
and c.[opt-in] = 1
```

Looks like you're creating a one-to-many relationship.  The primary key on your target data extensions will need to handle that.

Also, I adjusted the join to Orders to use userID.

Comment: Thanks Guys. @Adam, why did you change opt-in from 'true' to '1' ?

Comment: If your field is actually a Boolean field, the underlying data type is `bit` -- `1` represents true, `0` false.  No need to force a type conversion.

Comment: does this make the SQL quicker? In general, I mean.

Comment: Yes.  Reducing the number of type conversions will improve performance.